# MySQL Logical ALL

Tags: mysql, syntax

I'm trying to get a Logical ALL function working, but can't figure out the syntax.

I already have a boolean column in my data, and I'm trying to aggregate by some other column using a Logical ALL.

If my data is:

| category | value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| B | 0 |
| B | 0 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 0 |
| C | 0 |
| C | 1 |

My expected output is:

| category | ALL(value) |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 0 |
| C | 0 |

My naive attempt was:

SELECT category, ALL(value) FROM table
GROUP BY category;

Which gives a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `BIT_AND`:

```
SELECT category, BIT_AND(value) FROM tab GROUP BY category;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Sbcmj-SK)**